# Resources for Church's paper "An Unsolvable Problem of Elementary Number Theory"?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I'm trying to understand and breakdown into simple English Church's paper for "An Unsolvable Problem of Elementary Number Theory" but I'm not finding anything useful online, only citations and links to the full paper.

Does anyone know any resources I can get to help me understand this paper?

Comment: What about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsproblem)?

Comment: try [godels proof](http://www.amazon.com/G%C3%B6dels-Proof-Ernest-Nagel/dp/0814758371/) / Nagel, Neuman

Answer (score 3):

The article "[The Church-Turing Thesis](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/church-turing/)" of the [Standford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/) might help and/or provide references to texts that might be useful to you. The article by Joachim Breitner [Church’s undecidability result](http://www.joachim-breitner.de/various/ChurchTalk2011.pdf) might help you as well.